# A sequence of measurable functions doesn't converge with the following properties

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions defined on $[0,1]$ with the following properties:

1. $f_n(x)\in[0,1]$ for any $x\in[0,1]$ and $n\geq 1$.
2. $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[0,1]} f_n = 0$.
3. $\{f_n(x)\}$ doesn't converge for any $x\in[0,1]$.

My thought was to construct a sequence of functions that are zero almost everywhere to satisfy 2). For example, the Dirichlet function on $[0,1]$ and doesn't depend on $n$. But this sequence of functions seems not to satisfy 3) as it would converge to $1$ for any $x\in\mathbb{Q}$.

How do I construct such a sequence of functions? Any hints?

Comment: Why not take your approximating Dirichlet, shift it by some irrational, and finally mix them together?

Comment: Are you sure that such a function exists? By dominated convergence, we have $0 = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_n\,dx = \int_0^1 \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n \, dx$, so the limit of $f_n$ is zero almost everywhere, which contradicts property 3. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RichardChen Could you elaborate what you meant by mixing them together?

Comment: @jasnee Dominated convergence theorem requires that the sequence of functions to be pointwise convergent to a function, so I guess that this sequence of functions would not be pointwise convergent? But I cannot come up with any examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D = \{(k,m) \in \mathbb N^2 : m > 0, \; 0 \le k < m\}$. For $(k,m) \in D$, define $I_{(k,m)} = \left[ \frac{k}{m}, \frac{k+1}{m} \right]$. We can enumerate $D$ with a bijection $e \colon \mathbb N \to D$ sequentially, so $e(0) = (0,1)$, $e(1) = (0,2)$, $e(2) = (1,2)$, $e(3) = (0,3)$, $e(4) = (1,3)$, $e(5) = (2,3)$, and so on. The sequence $\{f_n\}$ where $f_n$ is the indicator function of $I_{e(n)}$ will satisfy the desired properties.

Intervals are measurable, so their indicator functions will be as well. Notice that the integral of the indicator function of $I_{(k,m)}$ is $\frac{1}{m}$, so these will converge to $0$. However, every point of $[0,1]$ gets 'visited' by infinitely many intervals in this sequence, so for any $x \in [0,1]$ the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ will be mostly $0$'s and the occasional $1$ but it will never stay $0$ forever, so it does not converge.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wonder how to ensure that $e$ is a bijection? Also, when we consider the integral of the indicator function $1/m$, are $k$ and $m$ also dependent on $n$?